# Python str to file type

Tags: python, http

I'm downloading an image with the requests library and then writing the image to disk, then reopening the new file to pass on into another function.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
r = requests.get(IMAGE_STREAM, stream=True)
output = StringIO.StringIO()
with open('1.jpg', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(r.content)

f = open('1.jpg')
img = Image.open(f)
```

Is there a method where I can skip the writing and reopening stage and pass the file straight into my end function?

Comment: As a side note, you really want to open the file in binary mode (`open('1.jpg', 'rb')`). Otherwise, your code may not work on Windows, will have problems if/when you port to Python 3, etc.

Comment: If you already know the type/mode/etc. of the file, you can just use `Image.fromstring`. But if you want PIL to guess that stuff for you from the headers, you have to pass it a file-like object. So, you can't skip the writing—but you can just write to a file-like object that isn't actually a file, like that `StringIO`.

Comment: Another side note: What are you using `stream=True` if you're just going to do a blocking `r.content`? The only reason to add the extra complexity of streaming is if you actually stream the data (e.g., via `iter_lines`).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, you have the `StringIO` object:

```
output = StringIO.StringIO(r.content)
```

Then just pass `output` to `Image.open`.

Comment: Links for details: From [the PIL.Image docs](http://www.pythonware.com/library/pil/handbook/image.htm), "You can use either a string (representing the filename) or a file object. In the latter case, the file object must implement read, seek, and tell methods, and be opened in binary mode." Since [`StringIO`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stringio.html) implements those methods, it will work.